# Executing C code from php

Tags: php, c

I am trying to compile and run an C file stored locally in my computer using php
i used the following piece of code

```
$dir = '/home/User/Desktop';
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
  mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.c', $code);

$path = "/home/User/Desktop/test.c";
$Command = "gcc $path 2&>1";
exec($Command,$return_val,$error);
```

i have set all the permissions to the file using chmod and chgrp
but on executing it just echos "Succesful" on my screen but not my $output value
This is the sample C program i typed in my

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello world");

return 0;

}
```

but the following program runs fine when i have executed it using GCC
i am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

i tried using

```
$Command = "gcc $path 2&>1"; $output = exec($Command); $output = exec(./a.out);
```

but still i cant get desired output

I tried to use

```
$output = exec($Command,$return_val,$error);
```

now when i echo $error it gives me "2"

I tried using system

```
$last_line = system('gcc $path', $retval);
echo '
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
```

i get the following output

```
Last line of the output: 
Return value: 4

sh: 1: cannot create 1: Permission denied
gcc: error: 2: No such file or directory
```

but i given permission to the file using

```
 sudo chmod g+w /home/User/Desktop/test.c
```

can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: C files are not executable. GCC compiles, links, then runs the executable that it creates from the C file. Why do you need to run an external executable?

Comment: You have to specify the created executable file in your `$path` variable, not the source code. The issue that your script outputs "Successful" is simply a result of the fact that you do not do any error checking at all. Without, how should your script know that something is wrong?

Comment: $Command = "gcc $path 2&>1";
$output = exec($Command);
$output = exec(./a.out);
thanks @foley but i tried even using GCC but still i cant get the $output value

Comment: Sorry, but I still can see no error handling there.

Comment: I am a new to php
can u please tell me how to do that?? @arkascha

Comment: Two separate ways: 1. take a look at the error log file your http server writes. That is where warnings, errors and everything are shown. Look at it! It is helpful! 2. take a look at the documentation of phps `exec()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php There is a third, optional parameter that allows to catch the processes return vallue. This tells you what happens...

Comment: thanks arkascha but i have read in some posts that adding the code "2>&1" to the end of your shell command,  redirects stderr to stdout,
so then atleast error should be present in $output

Comment: You indeed can redirect stderr to stdout and thus capture error output. _But_: this will only work if your process runs and outputs something to stderr.

Comment: A non-zero return value signal an error in the unix tradition. Apart from that: you did _not_ check the error log file. Not sure why, but you parsed the output of a CLI php call listing the configuration options.

Comment: OK, that information brings you closer. But again I am somewhat confused: I cannot spot any reasons why a shell should be involved here, yet your output says that some shell tries and fails to create some inode. Can it be that the top script is not the one used to create the output shown towards the bottom? And could you confirm that you are using php on CLI for this? It is executed under what local account? It looks like that, but you don't state that. The information would be valuable.

Comment: thanks @arkascha
in order to compile and execute my C program i need to use GCC shell command and moreover I have given all the permissions to the file by replacing 0744 with 0777 which gives me the permission to read,write and execute 
it is executed under group-'www-data'

Comment: So you are not using php under CLI, if I get that right. Using permissions of 0777 rarely is a good idea and typically not required. It is more something people try around with... GCC is not a shell command. It is an executable that should be invoked directly by your `system()` or `exec()` call, that is why I wonder. If so, the error message would mention `gcc` instead of `sh`. _Except_ if that `gcc` command you call is not the expected compiler, but some shell based wrapper... This looks very strange.

Comment: Even if we ignore that strange effect: I can't see where some shell command should try to "create" something. In the code above you create a directory, but from within php, not some shell. Something is missing here. Anyway: one issue might be that you do not specify an output file in your gcc call. So the compiler will try to create a file in its working directory. But it is unclear which that is. Either specify an output path in the gcc call (see its optional argument list) or switch the directory to `/home/User/Desktop` prior to running gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `2&>1`, it's `2>&1`.

```
sh: 1: cannot create 1: Permission denied
gcc: error: 2: No such file or directory
```

The first error you see here is the shell complaining about not being able to create a file named "1" to redirect stdout.
The second error is gcc complaining about the lack of an input file called "2".

Comment: Thanks a lot @aib that worked
sorry for that silly mistake